# Advanced Search - Is this possible?

Tags: wp-query, categories, query, search, plugin-recommendation

I am currently working on a Wordpress website that needs an advanced search adding to it.

I have three categories set up, each with a set amount of sub-categories, and then I'd like for a user to be able to select from three dropdown menus three different sub-categories.

So I'd have a set up like so:

cat1:

- cat1subcat1
- cat1subcat2
- cat1subcat3

cat2:

- cat2subcat1
- cat2subcat2
- cat2subcat3

cat3:

- cat3subcat1
- cat3subcat2
- cat3subcat3

I will create a post and add the post to a subcategory from each category, and then a user can search for a post that's in three specific subcategories.

For example, I'd like a user to be able to search for posts that are in cat1subcat1 AND cat2subcat1 AND cat3subcat1

I don't want there to be an actual search box for users to type in a query, I would just like the three dropdown menus.

Does anyone know if this is possible? I've looked at some plugins, but none seem to do this specifically.

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDITED TO ADD: This isn't a feature I want in a sidebar of the site. When a user goes to the homepage, the only thing they see on the page are the three dropdown menus. Another user suggested it's a filter, and whilst I'm aware that I can filter posts by category in a sidebar, this isn't what I need.

Comment: that doesn't sound like a search at all, it sounds like a category filter where you've chosen 3 categories. Note that if you're asking specifically if this is possible, then that makes writing an answer easy : "Yes", but I suspect a yes or no is not what you're looking for.

Comment: @TomJNowell - thank you for your reply. I guess a filter is what it is, however I want it to look and work like a search feature. I don't want it to be in a sidebar. The homepage will simply have the three dropdown menus and from there it will show posts in those three categories. Even on those pages I don't want a sidebar. I will look into this further though, thank you.